# move forward n indeces in matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I'm having a hard time believing this isn't a dupe, but I can't find *any* posts answering this question, so I'll try to make it a good one.

Essentially the problem is this: you have a matrix of size `Row X Column` and your number of processors is `P`.  The max size of your partition (the number of elements each processor is allocated) is `((Rows*Columns)/processors)+1`, and you'll have to do some logic to make sure you don't go out of bounds.  Each processor is assigned a starting point and must jump forward `P` indexes.

So on a 4x4 matrix which is sequentially numbered like the following:

> [1] [2] [3] [4]
>       [5] [6] [7] [8]
>       [9] [10][11][12]
>       [13][14][15][16]

a processor with id `0` would get 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, and 16. (the max partition size).

The algorithm my instructor gave us is like this:

> i / columns = row# and i % columns = column#

This worked for the examples he gave us like `6 / 4 = 1` and `6 % 4 = 2` so 6 is at index `[1][2]`
The logic is intuitive at least, but fails on several occasions.

So what is an algorithm which can reliably produce the indexes of the desired values on an `NxM` matrix?

Comment: Your problem statement is curious.  I don't see the advantage of thinking of this as a 2D matrix.  You seem to have an array that is round-robin partitioned over *n* processors.  Perhaps formulating the problem that way will help you understand the solution.

Comment: The assignment calls for the use of a matrix, and I'm quite sure the instructor will expect this algorithm on a test.

Comment: If you don't think those formulas work on some occasions, you should provide an example of a situation where you don't think it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "algorithm" given for calculating indices is based on all indices being zero-based, including the "matrix numbering":

```
    0  1  2  3

0   0  1  2  3
1   4  5  6  7
2   8  9 10 11
3  12 13 14 15
```

Now you can see that 6 really is at row 1 column 2.

Comment: Oh excellent, so the algorithm does work, I just have to add 1 to each index when iterating.  Thanks

Comment: Right. And possibly subtract 1 from the matrix index "i" that you're inputting first also.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an array that is round-robin partitioned over n processors.

As a hint to the solution (because this is class work), convert each matrix position into a position in the array, say *i*.  Then do the arithmetic on this number.

Comment: Is this the only sound way to get these values in a situation like this?  I wrote a function to do it this way, but it felt like I was sort of avoiding the assignment.